# java.lang.NullPointerException в JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

У меня есть небольшой проект на JavaFX. Мне нужно что бы текст, который я ввожу в TextField считывался и по нажатию кнопки выводился в консоль. Но выскакивает `java.lang.NullPointerException`. Помогите, плз.

```
public class ControllerMassage {

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane friendID;

    @FXML
    private TextField MassageField;

    @FXML
    private Button SendMassage;

    @FXML
    private Button FriendID1;

    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        SendMassage.setOnAction(event -> sendMassage1());
    }
    private void sendMassage1() {
        String massage = MassageField.getText();

        System.out.println(massage);
    }

}
```

Comment: Скорее всего из-за это строки `SendMassage.setOnAction(event -> sendMassage1());` Так как в инициализации вы пишете использование метода в котром должен прочитаться текст, который вы еще не ввели

Comment: Ну так это обработчик событий. Когда я нажимаю на кнопку, текст должен считаться с поля, а на момент нажатия кнопки текст в поле уже введен

Comment: а вы через дебаггер посмотрите, на момент нажатия, что там? К тому же, на какой строчке у вас эта ошибка выскакивает?

Comment: странно, я смодулировал ситуацию полностью, у меня все работает, а можно исключение полностью?

Comment: через дебаггер показывает, что MassageField = null. ошибка на строке String massage = MassageField.getText();

Comment: полностью не могу исключение скинуть, оно слишком большое

Comment: @ВладиславКукиль Добавьте его в сниппет

Answer (score -1):

Я не понял в чем была ошибка, но я просто пересоздал в `SceneBuilder` `TextField` и все заработало.